# How to send sms to multiple numbers in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, sms

I have used ngcordova plugin to send sms to a given mobile number.But now I want to send the same sms to multiple numbers.How can I implement this in ionic?

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Cordova sms](https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin) plugin

it has this method to send sms to multiple recipients.

```
sms.send('4155551234,4151234567', message, intent, success, error);
```

Regards.

Comment: thanks for the help.since this is a cordova plugin can I use it with ionic?

Comment: Ionic is just a library *on top* of cordova, so all cordova plugins should still work.

Comment: Yes its cordova plugin so you can use it. Full detail on installation and use is described there. @ErandakaAnupama

Comment: I have followed the instructions and build the app.In ionic serve when I check console no error occur when I tap the button to send sms. But the app is not working on real devise.I have add an alert to display whether msg sending is a success or fail.But either one of alert is also not displaying.I chage button onClick to ngClick since onClick is displaying an error in console.

Comment: what error is saying ? can you modify your answer with it ?